# Issue with raster stacking

Tags: python, rasterio, stack, earthpy

I tried raster stacking using the below code.I tried to read pixel values at a particular coordinate and few values are coming as zero where as when I tried reading the value before stacking there is some pixel value at that particular coordinate. I don't understand why my raster stacking is causing the issue.

```
from rasterio import plot
import os
import earthpy.spatial as es

    def image_stack(path, dest_file):
        band_fnames = os.listdir(path)
        band_paths = [path + fname for fname in band_fnames]
        arr, arr_meta = es.stack(band_paths, dest_file)
        return len(band_fnames)
```

Comment: what is `es`? it gives me some errors. Could you please add the imports as well?

Comment: I have added the import statements to the code

Comment: `listdir` will also list directories in `path`, you have only valid files in `path`?

Comment: Yes I have only the required files in the path mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the band count of the resultant stack, I have updated it's count and now the pixel values are non-zero .

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Could you please provide the code you used to solve the issue?